# Displaying all users on the same URL page

Tags: php, session, url

Is it possible to view all users on the same URL? I am using `$_SESSION['username']` to view the username when logged-in.

Example:

The full **URL** 1 is

```
https://www.example.com/admin/support.php?pager=1
```

Page 1 of the URL page

The full **URL** 2 is

```
https://www.example.com/admin/support.php?pager=2
```

Page 2 of the URL page

Using this code I can get the full URL of that page:

```
$link = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

So example in URL #1, if user 1, 2 and 3 is on that page it will show on that page their usernames. And in URL #2, If user 4 and 5 is in there, it will also show their usernames on that page (URL #2 not in URL #1).

What is the logic/way to implement this and to show every page all users on it?

Comment: It's been awhile since I worked with PHP, so unless PHP 7 has done some crazy magical stuff I'm going to go with: **No... Sort of**. You would have to register a session handler or something to store at the bare minimum the user's id#, the session#, and the current page. Using that info you could get all the users by their current page.

Comment: @Jhecht So, do I need to create a table on my database to store the URL of every users?

Comment: Effectively: yes.

Comment: @Jhecht Is there another simple way of doing it without using the database? How about storing them on cookies?

Comment: Cookies are only stored on the user's computer, PHP cannot simultaneously access the cookies on my computer and your computer, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Maybe saving in text file is possible. Thank you.

Comment: If that is the case, then perhaps a JSON file where the key is the current URL? I warn though if you plan on having a lot of users the read/write count on that file could be astronomical, and would definitely recommend a database.

Comment: Yes, I will try saving it in JSON file. I have only 6-10 users/admins. So I think it just okay to use it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTable or Normal Table to View all User in a Page by simple Query.

Don't use the url Parameter to get the user.

Use .htaccess for URL beautification because **xxx.com?id=1** is simply hack-able stuff.

Comment: Nope, I am not using parameter to get user. I am using $_SESSION for user. The parameter is for the pager of the page. Anyway thanks for suggestion using URL beautification.